# [Vue warn]: Property "myString" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex4

I use **version 3** of vuejs. I am trying to save the login username in my Login.vue.

As a first step, I try to save the content of an input field with the name "myString".

Unfortunately I get the error message: "[Vue warn]: Property "myString" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.".

What am I doing wrong ?

// **Login.vue** (Focus Part)

```
<template>
  {{ myString }}

  <input v-model="string" type="text" name="myString">
  <p>
    <button @click="setString">Set String</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button @click="deleteString">Delete String</button>
  </p>
</template>

<script>
import router from "@/router";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    Field,
    Form,
    ErrorMessage,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      string: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {},
  methods: {
    setString() {
      this.$store.commit("myString", this.string);
    },
    deleteString() {
      this.$store.commit("myString");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

// **main.js**

```
"use strict";
//exports.__esModule = true;

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
// import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import { createStore } from "vuex";

import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import SecureLS from "secure-ls";
const ls = new SecureLS({ isCompression: false });

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      string: ""
    }
  },
  /*plugins: [createPersistedState({
    storage: {
      getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
      setItem: (key, value) => Cookies.set(key, value, { expires: 3, secure: true }),
      removeItem: key => Cookies.remove(key)
    }
  })],*/
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      storage: {
        getItem: key => ls.get(key),
        setItem: (key, value) => ls.set(key, value),
        removeItem: key => ls.remove(key)
      }
    })
  ],
  mutations: {
    increment(state){
      state.count++;
    },
    decrement: state => state.count--,
    myString: (state, value) => value ? (state.string = value) : (state.string = "")
  },
})

const app = createApp(App)
.use(store)
.use(router)
.mount("#app")
```

// **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <navigation />
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Navigation,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ myString }}` is not defined.

You could get it from Vuex with a computed property

```js
computed: {
    mySting() {
        return this.$store.state.string
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tauzN, I have now added ```myString: "",``` to data in Login.vue. I haven't had any experience with computed. Where exactly do I use this in my construct? I do not yet fully understand the documentation in its interaction with my code. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values

Comment: @Julian If you are using the composition api [check this out](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html) do it like this: `myString: computed(() => store.state.string)`

Comment: Thanks @tauzN, it works !

i add
```import { computed } from 'vue'; import * as vuex from 'vuex'``` in the Login.vue and the setup part: 
setup () {
    const store = vuex.useStore()
    return {
      myString: computed(() => store.state.string)
    }
  },